# SQL DDL to support migration and updates

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, database-migration, ddl

I have a web app that uses a basic ms-sql DB only tables and constraints nothing special.

Every time i need to upgrade the schema of my DB I delete the old one and recreate a new one using a standard DDL script with a lot of create table clauses.

Is there any pattern that can make me write my DDL script in such a way that even when it will run on an existing DB it will update it without loosing all the stored date ?

Comment: Why do you delete the existing schema? Even when Migrating between different versions of sql server, most of the schema should not change at all.

Comment: Its required when upgrading the version of my web app .. I did not mean that im upgrading the version of the sql server.

Comment: Upgrading the web app includes making changes to the structure of the db tables .. But all i have is a DDL script with a bunch of create table statements .. That does not take into consideration the state of the existing db I'm upgrading .

Comment: Still this doesn't make too much sense to me. I can understand altering and adding tables, procedures or views, even deleting some of them, but I really don't understand why you need to delete the entire schema. This seems to me like a bad design.

Comment: Exactly. So im looking for a way to write my DDL scripts as a cumulative script that will make all the required changes for a version upgrade of an app..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked at Data Tools (also known as SSDT)? It's an add-in to Visual Studio that allows you to have (among other things) database projects. You add the objects in a declarative manner (i.e. `create table`, `create procedure`, etc) and the tool figures out how to make a target database look like the schema as represented in the DB project. But you still have to be careful! The tool will allow you to drop columns, tables, procedures, etc happily. But you can most certainly avoid dropping and recreating everything every time.